# NetworkX: add edges to a graph from a shapefile

Tags: python, networkx, shapefile, edges

Given the following test `shapefile`, which is made of polylines only:

[image]

I was able to reproduce the nodes of the spatial network represented in the shapefile:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.read_shp('C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder\TEST.shp') #Read shapefile as graph
pos = {k: v for k,v in enumerate(G.nodes())} #Get the node positions based on their real coordinates
X=nx.Graph() #Empty graph
X.add_nodes_from(pos.keys()) #Add nodes preserving real coordinates
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(X,pos,node_size=100,node_color='r')
plt.xlim(450000, 470000)
plt.ylim(430000, 450000)
```

[image]

Basically I have used a temporary graph `G` to extract the positions of the nodes that eventually appeared as part of the graph `X`. This seems to have worked just fine.

**My question:** following the same idea of using `G` to extract information from the shapefile, how could I plot the edges?

If I do something like this

```
X.add_edges_from(pos.keys())
```

Then I get this error, pointing at the line above:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: The code `X.add_edges_from(pos.keys())` raises an error because `pos.keys()` is a list of integers. In your case each edge needs to be specified by a tuple of 2 `int`s (because each node in `X` is of the type `int`). 


More importantly, [`nx.read_shp()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp.html#networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp) already generates the edges of the network. I don't understand why you are throwing those away...

Comment: I am plotting `X`, which nodes are `[0,1,2,...]`, so the edges of `X` must be `[(0,1),(0,2),...]`. You are right about `nx.read_shp()`, but if you type `G.edges()` you get a list where, in place of `(0,1)`, you see the coordinates of those two points. So I guess I need to map `G.edges()` onto `pos`. But I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to my comment:
`nx.read_shp()` holds the edge information as well. The graph `G` has nodes that look like `(x,y)`. The `pos` parameter to `draw_networkx_*` needs to be a dictionary with a node as a key and `(x,y)` as the value.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.read_shp('C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder\TEST.shp') #Read shapefile as graph
pos = {xy: xy for xy in G.nodes()}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=100,node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edge_color='k')
plt.xlim(450000, 470000)
plt.ylim(430000, 450000)
```

Comment: I really like this answer, thanks. It even preserves the directionality, in case one might want it.